# Secondary router preventing from accessing specific domains

Tags: networking, dns, wireless-router, ipv4

I live in a three story house, and unfortunately putting the router on the middle floor is not an option, reason why I get a very weak signal downstairs. I then decided to do what I did a couple of times before: use a PLC and connect an old router to the PLC (through one of its ethernet ports), in order to create a "new" network feeding from the main one. To do so, this is how I configured the secondary router:

1. Same gateway.
2. Same subnet mask.
3. Different IPv4 addresses pool (for the main one set to 192.168.0.[10,210], for the secondary 192.168.0.[211,254]).
4. Different SSID.
5. Different DNS servers. My secondary router let's you manually set the DNS servers it should use, but I could not use the same as in the main one because the ISP is not making them public nor visible in their routers' config.

Now the problem is that, for some reason I can't figure out, when both routers are on some servers aren't accessible from the main router. Notably, I can't access my job's virtual desktop if both routers are on. As you might've guessed, I have a really basic knowledge on the subject, and most of these decisions have been taken on a trial and error basis. It worked in the past but I'm sure somethings might seem nonsensical to you.

I haven't found any helpful article on the internet, even though I searched a lot, and my old router is neither configurable as a repeater, nor compatible with DD-WRT firmware. I hope you could tell me where the problem is, and how I should properly configure the router's to work as I intend: one connected to the network, the second connected to the former through ethernet using a PLC. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I stopped reading about halfway. Don't use routers, use Access Points, hardwired to the one & only actual router; or at worst, WiFI Extenders. That way your router is the only router in charge & everything else is subordinate. End of worries.

Comment: Can't a router be configured to work as a mere AP?

Comment: You are not configuring the router to work as a "mere AP".  According to point 2, you seem to be configuring it as a DHCP server in the same subnet as the other router which suggests it is running as a router with another NAT.

Comment: @tetech, is there something I then can do to make it work as an AP? If there is problem with my question, tell me, but "I would use an AP" is not an answer to how should I configure the router to work as intended. Of course, I would accept as an answer that there is no way to do it, but no one is actually saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off all router options for the second router.  That means turn off DHCP, turn off NAT, turn off DNS server.  Some routers might have a simpler "mode" option where setting it to "AP" does these things for you.

Do not use the WAN port on the router.  Plug everything in to LAN ports.  This way the router should be acting as a dumb switch and all devices should be getting their IP address from the primary router and seeing that as their gateway.

If wired connections work but wireless do not, it is possible that the wireless interface is not going through the switch (depends on router model/design).  Then you can alternatively set up the secondary router as though your primary is an internet provider.  This means don't try to have them on the same subnet and don't expect the two subnets to talk with each other, i.e. in this scenario expect them to be like two different houses.  This is less preferred.

If you cannot get either of these two approaches to work, then your particular router model may not be capable of being configured in that way, and you should investigate an extender.